# If $f : \Bbb{C} \to \Bbb{C}$ is entire, then $|f^{(n)}(0)| < n! n^n$ for some $n \in \Bbb{N}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to solve a problem that I can't seem to work out.

> $f$ is an entire function. Prove that $|f^{(n)}(0)|< n!n^n$ for at least 1 $n$.

I've been thinking to use the Cauchy estimates somehow but there's no reason for me to believe that $f$ is bounded from above.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Try proving it by contradiction. Suppose $|f^{(n)}(0)| \geq n! n^n$ for all $n \in \Bbb{N}$. You are given that $f$ is entire. Can you say anything about the radius of convergence of $f$ around $0$?

Answer (score 2):

Let $M  = \sup \{ |f(z)| : |z| = 1\}$. Since $f$ is entire, for all $n \ge 0$, we have

$$f^{(n)}(0) = \frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1} \frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz$$
Whenever $n > \max\{ 1, M \}$, this leads to
$$|f^{(n)}(0)| \le \frac{n!}{2\pi} \int_{|z|=1} |f(z)| |dz| \le 
\frac{n!}{2\pi} \int_{|z|=1} M |dz| = n!M
< n! n < n!n^n
$$